# How to display local image as button backgroundimage in Win8 HTML/JS app?

Tags: javascript

I am a young Austrian developer, starting my first HTML/Javascript Win8 App. I want to make a simple static reader app with grid layout. For this, I want to display backgroundimages (not like in the Visual Studio example just boring grey tones) stored localy in the Projectfolder (e.g. /images/test.png).

But - how to do that? I've found out that I need the help of Uri, but I am failing in using it properly. Here the code:

```
var uri = new Windows.Foundation.Uri('ms-appdata:///images/test.png');
var testpic = Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromApplicationUriAsync(uri);
```

I am always failing to display the picture, it just shows the standard image with an 'x' in the left corner to show me that it failed to load...

Questions: is the Uri statement correct? Is this the way to open a local file? What are the limits (size and filetypes) for the backgroundimages of these tiles(250px by 250px), maybe that is the problem?

Sorry for this questions, I am developing right now my first Windows specific and/or Javascript app, feeling a bit awkward with it. ;)

Sorry for my bad english, greetings from Austria! :)